# Swap positions of two consecutive lines exhibiting a common string

Tags: scripting, terminal

I have a text file with approx. 12 millions of lines, each composed of 4 fields (column 1, 2, 3 and 4)

Most lines have a unique STRING in column 2. I don't want to modify any of these lines.

Spread in the text file, I regularly have 2 consecutive lines with the same STRING in column 2. This roughly occurs 10,000 times in the entire text file. An example is shown hereunder:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4  
WT 1 ILS G  
WT 2 DSG E          
WT 3 WYT S 
. . . .  
WT 106  AAA X  
WT 106  BBB Y  
. . . .  
WT 2704 CCC X  
WT 2704 DDD Y   
. . . .
```

What I would I like to achieve:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4  
WT 1 ILS G  
WT 2 DSG E          
WT 3 WYT S 
. . . .  
WT 106  BBB Y    
WT 106  AAA X  
. . . .   
WT 2704 DDD Y   
WT 2704 CCC X  
. . . .
```

What resources do I have?

I have a text file with the 10,000 STRINGS that are present twice (106 and 2704 in my example here) and for which I need to swap the two lines.
I also know X and Y that are always the same in lines in which column2 is identical.

What I have done until now?

I know how to identify two lines with a common string (that I specify, for instance 106) and to swap them with sed.
What I don't know if how to make it dynamic (using the text file with the 10000 strings to identify) so I don't have I have to launch 10000 commands individually.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.
Best,

Laurent

Answer (score 5):

Brute force method in awk: always save one line, and promote any following lines that match it in field 1.

I tested on a million rows (with a single swap) and it ran in 5.5 secs, so your run should be just over one minute. It does not need your reference files.

The script, including a HereDoc with test rows.

```
#! /bin/bash

awkPairs () {

    local Awk='
FNR == 1 { k = $2; x = $0; next; } 
$2 != k { print x; k = $2; x = $0; next; } 
{ print $0; }
END { print x; }
'
    awk -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" ) -
}

    [ x ] && time awkPairs <<'[][]'
WT 1 One x1
WT 2 Two x2
WT 3 Three_1 x3
WT 3 Three_2 y3
WT 4 Four x4 
WT 5 Five_1 x5
WT 5 Five_2 y5
[][]
```

The (short) test run.

```
$ ./awkPairs
WT 1 One x1
WT 2 Two x2
WT 3 Three_2 y3
WT 3 Three_1 x3
WT 4 Four x4
WT 5 Five_2 y5
WT 5 Five_1 x5

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.006s
```

The script with all test material removed. It can be called with a single argument (the name of the input file), or with standard input redirected or piped in. The output always goes to stdout.

```
#! /bin/bash

awkPairs () {

    local Awk='
FNR == 1 { k = $2; x = $0; next; }
$2 != k { print x; k = $2; x = $0; next; }
{ print $0; }
END { print x; }
'
    awk -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" ) "${1:--}"
}

    awkPairs "${1}"
```

So it can be called in any of these ways:

```
./awkPairs myData.txt
./awkPairs < myData.txt
cat myData.txt | ./awkPairs
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your suggestion. I would like to test it but I don't see where my input file is? In addition, I slightly modified my question aince the common string is not in column 1 but 2 (I made a shortcut in my original question based on searching the common string and I realized it was not applicable to your suggestion). My apologizes for this. Best, L.

Comment: @Opus_francigenum  Amended and retested. the k (key) references changed from `$1` to `$2`. The test HereDoc stdin is replaced by a filename argument, which defaults to stdin if not supplied.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed in extended regex mode `-E` (this makes the regexes less noisy).  We hold two lines in the pattern space and compare the first fields of the two lines. Should they match, we print the swapped lines in the pattern space and read the next line.

```
sed -Ee '
  $!N
  s/^(\S+\s+(\S+)\s.*)\n(\S+\s+\2\s.*)/\3\n\1/
  t;P;D
' file
```

Note: this assumes no leading whitespace(s) in the 'file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion guest_7. I am currently testing it. I edited my question since your solution avoid using the known strings that are repeated. My common string is not in field 1, but field 2 of the text file.

Comment: I have edited the solution in response to the changes requirements,viz., of the grouping string being in column 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are only *pairs* of lines that needs swapping (i.e. not three or more consecutive lines that have the same second field), and that the file contains at least two lines:

```c
function possibly_swap() {
        if (stringa == stringb) {
                # The two previous lines needs swapping.
                t = linea
                linea = lineb
                lineb = t
        }
}

FNR >= 3 {
        possibly_swap()

        # Output the 2nd previous line (possibly swapped now).
        print lineb
}

{
        # Push new data.

        stringb = stringa
        lineb = linea

        stringa = $2
        linea = $0
}

END {
        # We may need to output the last two
        # lines swapped...
        possibly_swap()

        print lineb
        print linea
}
```

This `awk` program uses two sets of variables, `stringa` and `stringb`, and `linea` and `lineb`.  The `string` variables contains the strings, i.e. the second field from the input lines, for the two most recent lines.  The `line` variables contains the corresponding *full* lines.

The suffixes `a` and `b` used throughout the code corresponds the previous line and the line before that (the "2nd previous line").

You would put the code above into its own file (here I'm using `script.awk`) and run it on some other file (here `file`) as

```bsh
awk -f script.awk file
```

The same code as a "one-liner":

```bsh
awk 'FNR>=3{if(sa==sb){t=la;la=lb;lb=t}print lb}{sb=sa;lb=la;sa=$2;la=$0}END{if(sa==sb){print la;print lb}else{print lb;print la}}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python** has  a module and a function just for such kind of tasks, `itertools.groupby`.

It takes an iterator (in our case a file handle) and a criterion function which groups the data, in our case, a lambda function that groups on the second field of the data line.

The `[::-1]` is the`slice notation` for reversing a list.

```
python3 -c 'import sys
from itertools import groupby
ifile = sys.argv[1]
with open(ifile) as f:
  for k,g in groupby(f, lambda x: x.split()[1]):
    print(*list(g)[::-1],sep="",end="")
' file
```

Outputs:-

```
WT 1 ILS G  
WT 2 DSG E          
WT 3 WYT S 
. . . .
WT 106  BBB Y  
WT 106  AAA X  
. . . .
WT 2704 DDD Y   
WT 2704 CCC X  
. .    . .
```

---

`POSIX sed`

```
## helper variables for casting sed regexes
_s_='[:blank:]'
s="[${_s_}]" S="[^${_s_}]"
F="${S}\{1,\}" sep="${s}\{1,\}"
Fs=$F$sep

 sed -e "
  /\n/b
  h;\$q;N;G
  /^$Fs\($F\)$s.*\n$Fs\1$s.*\n/D
  P;s/.*\(\n.*\)\n.*/\1/;D
" file
```

---

`perl` can solve this as shown .

```
perl -lane '
  push @A, $_;
  if ($prev ne $F[1] || $.==1) {
    print shift @A if $.>1 && @A>1;
    $prev = $F[1];
  } else {
    print for reverse splice @A;
  }
  END { print for @A; }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
f {
    swap = $2 == p2
    print (swap ? $0 : prev)
}

!swap {
    prev = $0
    p2 = $2
    f = 1
}

END { if (f) print prev }' file
```

Delay printing by 1 record. Choose which record to print (current or previous) based on whether the current second field is the same as the previous one. If the current record is printed, `prev` is not updated. Consecutive records that have the same second field will be effectively shifted up by 1 position, with the first of those moved to the last position. At the end, the remaining record is printed (if any records were present in the input).

If you want to limit this "shifting" to a maximium number of consecutive records (e.g. to only swap pairs), just change `swap = $2 == p2` to `swap = $2 == p2 && f++ < 2`.